# Weird symbols while trying to move the cursor in text written in console

Tags: command-line, bash, c++, executable

i am new to Ubuntu.

I was running a c++ executable but i encountered this problem, the program asks for a written input but when i try to move the cursor with the arrow keys through the thing i wrote, i get these weird symbols instead: `^[[D`  `^[[C`. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely getting `^[[D` and `^[[C` codes for the left and right arrow keys because the C++ program does not provide any built-in line editing capability.

Line editing is usually provided in C/C++ programs via something like the [GNU readline library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). It may be possible to add it to a program that doesn't provide it natively using the `rlwrap` utility - see for example [Is there something like cat with history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472426/is-there-something-like-cat-with-history).